# Sum rows with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have a DataTable like this:

[image]

I want to sum rows with J = 340 together, 341 together and so on until J = 120 for 6 years (2006 - 2012). But J value of 340-365 for last year should not be in summation.

I used this way at first to sum values with dates (without linq):
(year = 6)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= year; i++)
{
    DataRow[] foundRow = dataTable.Select("Dates =" + temp.ToString());
    aggregateValue += Convert.ToDouble(foundRow[0]  ["Values"].ToString());

    if (innerCounter % year == 0)
    {
        DataRow newRow = newDT.NewRow();

        newRow["sum"] = aggregateValue / innerCounter; 
        newDT.Rows.Add(newRow);
        aggregateValue = 0;
        innerCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

this solution is good for me, but for '29Feb', I (in fact our team) decide to use J to sum same J values to cover the affect of "29Feb" for leap years.

Thank you,

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: It is a simple linq operation. Why do you have problems to implement it?

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov it will consider the last year J values. This values should be summed(for example): 341(2006) + 341(2007) + 341(2008) + 341(2009) + 341(2010) + 341(2011).

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the sum of any column in datatable using linq like this:

```
table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));
```

In your case it will be like this:

```
table.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.Field<int>("J") < 340 && x.Field<int>("J") > 365).Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("J"));
```

Where condition you can modify as per your need. In above where condition it will not calculate J values which are between 340 to 365

Comment: but I need 349 <= j =< 120 for example

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
//find the max year
var lastRecord = table.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.Field<DateTime>("Dates")).First();
//if you want to filter by predefined year - change the value of lastYear
var lastYear = lastRecord.Field<DateTime>("Dates").Year;

var aggregates = table.AsEnumerable()
    //grouping by J and Year to exclude uninterested records
    .GroupBy(f => new
        { 
            J = f.Field<int>("J"), 
            Year = f.Field<DateTime>("Dates").Year 
        })
    //excluding records with unsatisfactory conditions
    .Where(f => (f.J < 340 || f.J  > 365) && f.Year != lastYear)
    //combining remaining records into one sequence
    .SelectMany(f => f)
    .GroupBy(f => f.J)
    .Select(f => new 
    {
        J = f.Key,
        SumValues = f.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Values"));
    });
```

The resulting sequence will contain sums with `J` flag.